# Building a stopwatch timer in excel even when it's auto refreshing

Tags: excel, vba, database, sharepoint, stopwatch

So I have some data that I collect in a spreadsheet for orders and I'm trying to track order fulfillment times in real time on the spreadsheet. The when the order is received and I start working on it, I change the order status to O. I want a timer to start in the cell next to it when O is entered. Once the order is fulfilled, I change the status to C. I want the timer to stop when I do that. The goal is to keep all fulfillment times under 30 minutes so any time between 0:00 – 14:59 fills in green, 15:00 – 29:59 fills orange, 30:00+ fills red.

I have found code to do this, but the problem is that the spreadsheet lives on SharePoint and is being updated from multiple users so it refreshes every time a change is made. Whenever the document refreshes, the timer starts back at 0. Is there a way to make the timer ONLY be triggered by the cell value for the order status? Below is a picture of what I want the document to look like. Is this possible in excel, or is there another program I can use? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

[Mockup of what I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afWFW.png)

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). How are we supposed to tell you what you did wrong if we don't even know what you did? • Actually you just need 2 columns. One where VBA writes the start time (when you turn status to `O`) use the worksheet_change event for that. And a second column that has a formula calculating the difference between now and the start time. With the change event when the status is turned into `C` change that formula into a value using `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value` where `A1` is the cell to change.

Comment: Thanks! Would that still be able to work with the document refreshing every time a change is made though?

Comment: If you do what I said (using a formula) this will refresh everytime you press F9 or calculate anything on the sheet.